# Test Windows Server

Tags: windows

I would like to test Windows server (any version) , how do I install Windows virtually on my Windows XP machine? I donot have a CD of Windows Server, is it available freely? Please guide me .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You can download [Microsoft's Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) for the hypervisor.

As for the CD's you can download 180 day trials of most Microsoft software.
[Windows Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb430831.aspx)
[Windows Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

I concur with @Blake about Virtual PC, but rather than download ISO images and install the OS from scratch, why not download a pre-installed test VHD file? Good for 180 days as well. Here you'll find all available [VHD images from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb738372.aspx).

Comment: Most of Microsoft's prebuilt vhd's are only compatible with Hyper-v which is alot harder to come by than virtual pc.

Comment: Not necessarily. I've been using their VHDs with Virtual Server 7 for over 2 years now. Also, Hyper-V is a free product as well now (although MS thought about charging for it at first, they soon realized the technology is out there for free already).